# Laravel: Accepted to call a model function inside view?

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller I return an array into my view which contains an author ID, that ID needs to be converted to the name with another get from the database so I am wondering if it's accepted to call a model function from inside my view?

What I'm trying to do is to pass an ID to the function which collects the data from the database and returns the name of the author with the correct ID.

This is how i wrote it in the view:

```
{{ User::getUserName($post['author']);  }}
```

The end result is an echoed Full Name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible, but it's **bad design.**

In MVC, the controller's role is to manage the user requests (received as HTTP GET or POST requests when the user clicks on GUI elements to perform actions). Its main function is to call and coordinate the necessary resources / objects needed to perform the user action. Usually the controller will fetch data from the model layer for the task and then select the proper view, or manipulate models after a user input has happened.

So by directly calling your model from the view layer, you circumvent the application logic contained in your controllers, which is messy (and unexpected for any other developer having to work with your project).

The proper MVC way: Fetch your model in the controller action that outputs your view and have the controller pass the model on to your view.

Comment: Not always the best solution. For instance, lets say you have a `header.blade.php` and you'd like to show the amount of notifications unread. Now, this header is called in 20 different pages, if you handle this in controllers, you'll have to call it in 20 controllers. If you add more information to the header, retrieved by DB, you'll have to edit 20 files. Also, if you create a new controller you must track what goes into the header file...see where this is going?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for you would be, of course if possible, to pass a collection or an array of Post objects to view instead of that array. This would allow you to use the relationship between Post and User and have something like this in your view:

```
{{ $post->author()->full_name }}
```

which is the preferred way to do things in MVC architecture